# is django overkill for a contact us website?

Tags: python, django, vue.js, web

I'm a complete beginner and a relative of mine asked me to build a simple 'contact us' website for them. It should include some information about his company and a form in which people that visit the website are able to send mails to my relative. I have been playing around with vue.js in order to build the frontend. I now want to know how to put the form to send mails and I read it has to be done with backend, so I thought I could use django as I have played with it in the past and I am confident using python. Is it too much for the work that I have to do? Should I use something simpler? I accept any suggestions please, Thanks.

Comment: I've done it before, did the job. But then I ended up just using a wix site since it was easier for the client to update themselves

Comment: Yes it is overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably should use something ready like Wix or Wordpress if want to do it fast if you prefer to learn in the process you can do it with Django and Vue, but this is indeed little bit overkill

Answer (score 0):

**Flask**

You can use Flask. it is simpler than Django and easy to learn. you can build a simple website like the one you want in less than 50 line.

---

**Wordpress**

If you want you can use Wordpress. it's easy to install and many hosting services support it already. Wordpress has so many plugins and templates to build contact us website in 10 minutes.

---

**Wix**

wix is easy, drag-n-drop website builder with many pre-build templates that you can use, check them out and you will find what you need.